# Can I compile a Java App to a single binary that runs on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, jwrapper, packr

There shouldn't be any additional requirements to configure a JRE or JAVA_HOME and all that. I'd like to bundle a jre (ideally the IBM JRE) within the binary.

I've looked at the following tools:

JWrapper: Seems to require a splash screen which I don't need because I'm developing a console application

packr: Doesn't seem to work with the IBM JRE only the Oracle and OpenJDK ones.

Jar2Exe: Doesn't seem to work with the IBM JRE either.

Everything else seems to only work for windows.

Are there any other tools I'm not aware of? Should packer and Jar2EXE actually work with the IBM JRE but I'M doing something wrong?

Comment: You can't bundle a JRE inside an executable, unless you're talking about an install program, but it doesn't sounds like that's what you're saying.

Comment: No I don't mean an install program. I mean a single executable which contains the executable jar and the jre to run it against. It shouldn't be obvious to the user that java is being used in any way.

Comment: Is Native packaging an option? It is part of Java 8 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try [Excelsior JET](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/). 
I'm not sure about IBM JRE (there is a [thread](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiFnqXVu4nPAhWKNJoKHdF5B0cQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.excelsior-usa.com%2Fforum%2Ftopic%2F815-compiling-java-application-that-uses-ibm-jrejdk%2F&usg=AFQjCNGEbWZZ0f_bbHjX0TPmXA0Nq36_Fw&sig2=b-G6htJGCvf-7KsmZEed_Q) about it), but it works perfectly with Oracle JRE and OpenJDK.

Comment: You can generate Linux Binaries with it? I've downloaded a trial version but it seems to only want to let me generate .EXE files.

Comment: You had to download the trial for Linux. Cross-compilation is not yet supported.

Comment: @Vadeg Excelsior JET has its own Java runtime, so it does not need a JRE or JDK. (Technically, we build the Platform API from licensed Oracle code, but the JVM is our own clean-room implementation).